# Dose the if statement recognize the answer Scanner(System.in).nextLine() received?

Tags: java

If does not work when Y is entered as the statement.
+And how do I read and change config.cfg file?

My code is as below.

```
package myfirstpgram;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MidiBot {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, SecurityException, IOException {
        File FolderDD = new File("./ProgramMF_Data"); // Set Program data to var(./ProgramMF_Data)
        try {
            FolderDD.mkdir();  // create Folder ProgramMF_Data
            System.out.println("successfully created folder."); // print success to create folder
        }
        catch(Exception e) { //Catch error
            e.getStackTrace(); // ?
            e.printStackTrace(); // print error info 1
            System.out.println("ERROR1 - Can't create Directory."); // print error info 2
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Did you run the program for the first time? [Y/n]");
        String FirstEM;
        FirstEM = sc.nextLine();
        if ("Y".equals(FirstEM)) {
            System.out.println("Please Create ./ProgramMF_Data/config.cfg");
            System.out.println("and set content like below");
            System.out.println("\n[Config]"); //   
            System.out.println("FirstTime=1"); //  
            Thread.sleep(60000); // Sleep 60 seconds
            System.out.println("\nProgram closes in 4 seconds!"); // info
            Thread.sleep(4000); // sleep 4 seconds
            System.exit(0); // Close program
        }
        System.out.println("Welcome again"); // print "Welcome again"
   }
}
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase.

Comment: What is the output you get when you write `System.out.println("length: "+FirstEM.length()+", content:"+FirstEM);` before the `if()` statement?

Comment: Your code does not even compile (`sc` was never created).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code seems correct, though an issue could arise when you enter a lower case "y".
a better approach would be

```
"y".equalsIgnoreCase(FirstEM);
```

And also you need to initialize scanner.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

as for the config file, if it is a properties file then
[check this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-the-data-from-a-properties-file-in-java)

Comment: Note that Java also already has a config-file system built-int. It is a bit old though, `Properties` is the name of the class.

Comment: if it is a properties file check out this link (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-the-data-from-a-properties-file-in-java)

Comment: "your code seems correct" - the scanner `sc` was never created. The code does not compile. You might want to add this to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare and initiaize a scanner before being able to use it
Please add `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` before using it.

I would also recommend you to take a small break and look up some [naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).

Comment: Thanks! But I added my code, but it's still not work.  But 1 error is solved!

Comment: @AsCody94 Not sure why you accepted the other answer then!? If you have a new question, you can open a new question :-D